# How to avoid changing the week day starting number when changes the phone Region in settings in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

Hello I am getting the starting day number of the week in this way

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"c"];
    NSString *dayofweek=[formatter stringFromDate:startdate];
```

This `strdate` is a like 11/01/2016.

Then I convert it into a `int`and my button width is 41 so I take the X position where should I place this starting date button in this way.

```
int wday=[dayofweek intValue];
posx=41*wday;
```

My days name arranged like this.

S   M   T   W   TH   F   S

My problem is when I change my phone region to Austrailia it takes this `wday` as 3. But If I changed the region to an Asian country `wday` takes as 2.

How can I solve this issue?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get a locale-independent weekday use:

```
NSInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar]
                                  components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday
                                    fromDate:startDate].weekday;
```

Comment: NSInteger is not a structure or union,, I am getting this error message